# Removing items from a ListAdapter not working

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

```
@Override  
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
  if(item.getTitle()=="Remove"){
   AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
   quotesAdapter.remove(quotes.get((int)info.id));
   quotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   listView.setAdapter(quotesAdapter);
   serializeQuotes();
  }  
  else {
   return false;
  }  

  return true;  
 }
```

Doesn't do anything. If I add

`this.quotesAdapter = new QuoteAdapter(this, R.layout.mainrow, quotes);`

Removal works, but I don't think is the right way of doing things. I'm not sure what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If `quotes` is a Java array, that is unmodifiable at runtime. Try using an `ArrayList<>` instead.

If `quotes` is a `Cursor`, you need to delete the row from the underlying database, then `requery()` the `Cursor`.

Comment: quotes is an ArrayList<Quote>

Comment: Try using `info.position`, then, instead of `info.id`. `position` is the index into your array; `id` probably has no value.

Comment: both info.position and id return a value as I can print the object to the console. Unfortunately, it is still not being removed from the list.